What are the possible solutions for performing full matching on a dataset with a size of 61,000?
I am working with a dataset of approximately 61,000 observations (with 27,686 treatment and 32,405 controls) and need to perform full matching using the MatchIt package in R. I am encountering performance issues and lengthy computation times. This is the error I get
Error in `matchit()`: ! (from optmatch) result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
What are the potential solutions or best practices for performing full matching with MatchIt on such a large dataset? Specifically, I am looking for ways to optimize the matching process or alternative approaches that can handle large datasets efficiently.
Any advice on parameter tuning, parallel processing, or other techniques that can improve the performance of full matching in MatchIt would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

This question should be reopened, as it is a statistical methods question.

Taken from the MatchIt vignette on choosing a matching method:

For large datasets (i.e., in 10,000s to millions), some matching
methods will be too slow to be used at scale. Instead, users should
consider generalized full matching, subclassification, or coarsened
exact matching, which are all very fast and designed to work with
large datasets.

Generalized full matching (method = "quick") is specifically designed to mimic full matching but has support for large datasets and runs very fast. Subclassification (method = "subclass") is also very fast since it doesn't require any matching, but it relies more strongly on having a well-estimated propensity score (whereas generalized full matching can be done using any distance metric, e.g., the Mahalanobis distance). With large sample sizes like yours, you should request many subclasses (upwards of 100). Like with full matching, all units are retained.

Hi @Noah. Could we fit a lasso regression first and then use only relevant predictors in MatchIt?

@CharlyMarie Yes, that is one of the options in MatchIt. Just remember you have to assess and obtain balance on all confounders even if they are not selected by the lasso. Whether a lasso propensity score or an unregularized propensity score yields better balance is an empirical question specific to the nature of your dataset, so try both. But don't think that just because the lasso doesn't select a predictor, you don't have to assess and obtain balance on it.

Thank you all for your comments.
@Noah.  I can perform 1:1 nn caliper matching. Could you please provide some resources on effect estimations when using caliper matching? I've spent some time on Stuart & Greifer 2023 and Greifer 2023 already.

@eshuns Everything you need to know is in those documents. Did you try the methods I recommend? They often perform better than 1:1 NN matching with a caliper, which has many problems.

@Noah, I appreciate your continuous assistance.
I am interested in the ATT, so I was trying to following the recommendations in Greifer & Stuart, 2023 since the ATT was suggested for these matching processes: Pair matching (e.g., nearest neighbor, optimal) without a caliper, Full matching, Fine stratification. I am having issues with full matching now, so I would have to try the others.

If you're trying to estimate the ATT, then you should avoid a caliper. Generalized full matching can target the ATT and is designed for large datasets. Did that not solve your problem?

@Noah. Yes, the Generalized full matching worked. Thank you!

Support for the particular package isn't really what you get here.
Is there some categorical variable that is possibly the most important matching variable? If so, you could look at each category for this variable individually. If that's not the case, consider a different matching algorithm or a different implementation that's more memory efficient.
Globally matching across all variables at once without any hierarchy does involve using all comparisons across records and doing operations across all those comparisons (maybe there are clever strategies to do this in a memory efficient way, so do you research on what's already out there, it'll be hard to come up with a home-cooked solution quickly).
In comparison, some other algorithms that may not achieve the globally optimal matching can be a lot faster and memory efficient, by iteratively matching some records at a time. E.g. greedily matching the best matching records first and proceeding from there can be implemented much more efficiently, because while you need to compare all records vs. each other you don't need to hold that in memory all at once (e.g. you can just iterate through all pairs of records and only keep the $M$ best matching pairs of records and how well they match in memory, you then replace one of them, if you find something better).
